# how to give relative path for source files in xcode?

Tags: xcode5

i have common folder for all source,include files like inc--->filename.h,source files--->filename.c,filename.cpp.I wanted xcode to just take refernce of all source files.I got it by the option "create folder references for any added folders and i gave header paths using "header search path".When i tried to build i had zero source files ,then i manually added all source files needed by using "relative to group".

I want to give relative path with refernce to filename.xcodeproj folder so that it wont turn red even if some builds the code using another mac.Because their directory structure will be different from mine.My question is how to give relative path for source files.Is there any option in xcode like we give header paths using "header search path"??

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand side where files are listed, click on one of the files.  Then, on the right hand side of the project where it says "Identity and Type" you'll see a "Location" drop-down box.  Yours probably says "Absolute Path" which is tied to your directory structure.

Make that "Relative to Group", or whatever else you might need.